# Calculating the power supplied by the current and voltage sources

Tags: voltage, power, integrated-circuit, current-measurement, network

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftlK5q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have attended one exam where I was asked to solve this Question. Generally the Power is nothing but the product of current and voltage in a network. But here the question is to calculate the power delivered by current and voltage source individually. So how can I proceed to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a trick question? (I suppose ideal source). You cuold use superposition or you can see current source (for instance) and resistor as a real current source and replace it with dual voltage source. In both case you can calculate current, but you want power delivered to the resistor or absolute value supplied to all the circuit?

Comment: @Antonio It is how much the power is supplied by each sources separately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Generally the Power is nothing but the product of current and voltage

You are right !

You just have to calculate the voltage across the current source, and the current in the voltage source, multiply the related current and voltage, and you'll get the answers.

- for the current source : the voltage is 12V (the same of the voltage source, because they are in parallel). The power is 6A * 12V = 72W
- or the voltage source : you have first to calculate the current flowing in the source, which is the difference between the current in the resistor and the current of the current source. I = 4A - 6A = -2A. And the power is : -2A * 12V = -24W. The minus sign tells the voltage source will RECEIVE 24W

**[ADDED]**
Oh, and by the way : the power in the resistor is 12V * 4A = 48W. You can check that it is equal to the algebraic sum of the powers of the two sources:
48W = 72W + (-24W)