# Power supplied by the current and voltage sources (problem)

Tags: homework, superposition

I have to find the power supplied by the current and voltage sources below. The correct answers are as follows.

$$P_{I}=\frac{1}{2}E_{s}I_{s}+\frac{3}{2}RI_{s}^{2}$$
$$P_{E}=\frac{1}{2}E_{s}I_{s}-\frac{1}{2R}E_{s}^{2}$$

I understand that if I short circuit the voltage source the total resistance(Rt) becomes (3/2)R and the power supplied becomes (3/2)RIs^2. If I replace the current source with an open circuit, Rt becomes 2R thus the power becomes (1/2R)Es^2.

Where does that (1/2)EsIs part come from? Why is it 1/2?

I have seen  [Calculating the power supplied by the current and voltage sources](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/239831/calculating-the-power-supplied-by-the-current-and-voltage-sources), but I still don't get it.

[image]